# Two more more threads writing the same value to the same memory location

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, locking, pthreads

I have a situation where several threads write the same value to the same memory location.

Can this lead to the memory location storing a corrupt value resulting from the concurrent writes ?

Let's say I have an object of class A with a unique id. When it is used by threads, these threads will assign a certain id to them, say 100. My question is : can the id be a value other than 100 after all of the threads write 100 to this memory location? In other words, do I have to protect this id with a mutex ?

Comment: That could be platform dependent. You need to know whether this write would be atomic, try searching this in docs or google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think multiple non-atomic writes of the same value are guaranteed to be safe (i.e. producing the same result as one write) if these two conditions hold:

- a non-atomic write is constructed from a series of atomic writes
- several atomic writes of the same value to a location produce that same value

Both of these seem to be natural enough to expect, but I am not sure they are true for every possible implementation.

The example I am thinking of is the following:

Suppose two processes write the 2-byte value `1` to some address `a`. The value is written as two separate atomic bytes: `1` to address `a`, and `0` to address `a+1`. Now if we have two processes (`P`,`Q`), both writing first the value `1` to address (say) `10`, then writing the value `0` to address `11`, then without mutual exclusion we get the following possible executions:

- `P[1->10]`,`P[0->11]`,`Q[1->10]`,`Q[0->11]`
- `P[1->10]`,`Q[1->10]`,`P[0->11]`,`Q[0->11]`
- `P[1->10]`,`Q[1->10]`,`Q[0->11]`,`P[0->11]`
- `Q[1->10]`,`Q[0->11]`,`P[1->10]`,`P[0->11]`
- `Q[1->10]`,`P[1->10]`,`Q[0->11]`,`P[0->11]`
- `Q[1->10]`,`P[1->10]`,`P[0->11]`,`Q[0->11]`

Either way we write `1` twice to location `10`, and write `0` twice to location `11` atomically. If the two writes produce the same result as one write, then either of the above sequences produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, be conservative and protect your critical section using a mutex. This way, you are guaranteed that your code will work correctly on every possible platform.

Comment: I cannot imagine a situation where this will lead to a corrupt value because the values written to the memory location are the same.

Can you give an example of what could happen on a platform where my algorithm will break? i.e. the id ends up being some other value due to concurrent writes.

Comment: @takwing: See *Suor*'s comment on the OP.